# GNU-C toolchain setup.c issue for ARM Cortex M3

Tags: c, gcc, arm, texas-instruments, gnu-toolchain

I am using an ARM M3 based MCU, CC2538. I use Code Composer Studio v6 as an IDE. When I select GNU v4.7.4 (Linaro) as a compiler, I get a warning message that " selected device does not currently provide  project initialization details to the GNU toolchain". I assume it is due to `setup.c`(?) that will be added later on.

the compiler has the following flags

```
 `"-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfpu=vfp -I"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/arm-none-eabi/include" -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -mno -thumb-interwork -msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd"
```

and linker flags: `-mthumb -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -Wl,-Map,"cc2328em_test.map"`

I use the source files provided by TI http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/swra443

I add main.c, setup.c, setup_gcc.c, and cc2538_512.cmd into an empty project, then compile it. here is the compile output:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project cc2328em_test ****

"c:\\ti\\ccsv6\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k all 
'Building file: ../main.c'
'Invoking: GNU Compiler'
"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfpu=vfp -I"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/arm-none-eabi/include" -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -fshort-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -o"main.o"  "../main.c"
'Finished building: ../main.c'
' '
'Building file: ../setup.c'
'Invoking: GNU Compiler'
"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfpu=vfp -I"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/arm-none-eabi/include" -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -MMD -MP -MF"setup.d" -MT"setup.d" -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -fshort-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -o"setup.o"  "../setup.c"
'Finished building: ../setup.c'
' '
'Building file: ../startup_gcc.c'
'Invoking: GNU Compiler'
"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfpu=vfp -I"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/arm-none-eabi/include" -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -MMD -MP -MF"startup_gcc.d" -MT"startup_gcc.d" -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd -fshort-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -o"startup_gcc.o"  "../startup_gcc.c"
'Finished building: ../startup_gcc.c'
' '
'Building target: cc2328em_test.out'
'Invoking: GNU Linker'
"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -mthumb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -Wl,-Map,"cc2328em_test.map" -nostartfiles -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -o"cc2328em_test.out" "./main.o" "./setup.o" "./startup_gcc.o" "../cc2538_512_gcc.cmd"  -Wl,--start-group -l"c" -l"gcc" -l"nosys" -Wl,--end-group 
./startup_gcc.o:(.flashcca+0x0): multiple definition of `__cca'
./setup.o:(.flashcca+0x0): first defined here
c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: ../cc2538_512_gcc.cmd contains output sections; did you forget -T?
c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cc2328em_test.out section `.flashcca' will not fit in region `FLASH_CCA'
c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: region `FLASH_CCA' overflowed by 12 bytes
c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00200000
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [cc2328em_test.out] Error 1
gmake: Target `all' not remade because of errors.

**** Build Finished ****
```

here is the first error "**./startup_gcc.o:(.flashcca+0x0): multiple definition of `__cca'**"

Does the source code have a mistake? Do I use a wrong toolchain (I downloaded the GNU tool chain from TI's APP center as "ARM GCC" with GCC logo. or do I miss any configuration?

---

Here are the source files that TI supplies:

**main.c**

```
#define GPIO_C_DIR              0x400DB400
#define GPIO_C_DATA             0x400DB000

#define HWREG(x)                                                              \
    (*((volatile unsigned long *)(x)))

int main(void)
{
    volatile unsigned long ulLoopCount;

    // Set direction output and initial value for PC2 and PC0
    // Greed LED on PC2
    // Red LED on PC0
    HWREG(GPIO_C_DIR) |= 0x05;
    HWREG(GPIO_C_DATA + (0x05 << 2)) = 0;

    // Loop forever.
    while(1)
    {
        // Turn on both LED's.
        HWREG(GPIO_C_DATA + (0x05 << 2)) ^= 0x05;

        // Delay for a bit
        for(ulLoopCount = 200000; ulLoopCount > 0; ulLoopCount--)
        {
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**setup.c**

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define FLASH_START_ADDR                0x00200000
#define BOOTLOADER_BACKDOOR_DISABLE     0xEFFFFFFF
#define SYS_CTRL_EMUOVR                 0x400D20B4
#define SYS_CTRL_I_MAP                  0x400D2098


//*****************************************************************************
//
// Customer Configuration Area in Lock Page
// Holds Image Vector table address (bytes 2013 - 2015) and
// Image Valid bytes (bytes 2008 -2011)
//
//*****************************************************************************
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t ui32BootldrCfg;
    uint32_t ui32ImageValid;
    uint32_t ui32ImageVectorAddr;
}
lockPageCCA_t;

#ifdef __IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__
__root const lockPageCCA_t __cca @ ".flashcca" =
#elif __TI_COMPILER_VERSION__
#pragma DATA_SECTION(__cca, ".flashcca")
#pragma RETAIN(__cca)
const lockPageCCA_t __cca =
#else
__attribute__ ((section(".flashcca"), used))
const lockPageCCA_t __cca =
#endif
{
  BOOTLOADER_BACKDOOR_DISABLE,  // Bootloader backdoor disabled
  0,                            // Image valid bytes
  FLASH_START_ADDR              // Vector table located at flash start address
};
```

---

**startup_gcc.c**

```
#include "setup.c"


//*****************************************************************************
//
// Macro for hardware access, both direct and via the bit-band region.
//
//*****************************************************************************
#ifndef HWREG
#define HWREG(x)                                                              \
        (*((volatile unsigned long *)(x)))
#endif


extern int main (void);

void ResetISR(void);
void NmiSR(void);
void FaultISR(void);
void IntDefaultHandler(void);

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Reserve space for the system stack.
//
//*****************************************************************************
static uint32_t pui32Stack[128];



__attribute__ ((section(".vectors"), used))
void (* const gVectors[])(void) =
{
   (void (*)(void))((uint32_t)pui32Stack + sizeof(pui32Stack)), // Stack pointer
   ResetISR,                               // Reset handler
   NmiSR,                                  // The NMI handler
   FaultISR,                               // The hard fault handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 4 The MPU fault handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 5 The bus fault handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 6 The usage fault handler
   0,                                      // 7 Reserved
   0,                                      // 8 Reserved
   0,                                      // 9 Reserved
   0,                                      // 10 Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 11 SVCall handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 12 Debug monitor handler
   0,                                      // 13 Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 14 The PendSV handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 15 The SysTick handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 16 GPIO Port A
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 17 GPIO Port B
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 18 GPIO Port C
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 19 GPIO Port D
   0,                                      // 20 none
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 21 UART0 Rx and Tx
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 22 UART1 Rx and Tx
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 23 SSI0 Rx and Tx
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 24 I2C Master and Slave
   0,                                      // 25 Reserved
   0,                                      // 26 Reserved
   0,                                      // 27 Reserved
   0,                                      // 28 Reserved
   0,                                      // 29 Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 30 ADC Sequence 0
   0,                                      // 31 Reserved
   0,                                      // 32 Reserved
   0,                                      // 33 Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 34 Watchdog timer, timer 0
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 35 Timer 0 subtimer A
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 36 Timer 0 subtimer B
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 37 Timer 1 subtimer A
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 38 Timer 1 subtimer B
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 39 Timer 2 subtimer A
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 40 Timer 2 subtimer B
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 41 Analog Comparator 0
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 42 RFCore Rx/Tx
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 43 RFCore Error
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 44 IcePick
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 45 FLASH Control
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 46 AES
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 47 PKA
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 48 Sleep Timer
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 49 MacTimer
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 50 SSI1 Rx and Tx
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 51 Timer 3 subtimer A
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 52 Timer 3 subtimer B
   0,                                      // 53 Reserved
   0,                                      // 54 Reserved
   0,                                      // 55 Reserved
   0,                                      // 56 Reserved
   0,                                      // 57 Reserved
   0,                                      // 58 Reserved
   0,                                      // 59 Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 60 USB 2538
   0,                                      // 61 Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 62 uDMA
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 63 uDMA Error
#ifndef CC2538_USE_ALTERNATE_INTERRUPT_MAP
   0,                                      // 64 64-155 are not in use
   0,                                      // 65
   0,                                      // 66
   0,                                      // 67
   0,                                      // 68
   0,                                      // 69
   0,                                      // 70
   0,                                      // 71
   0,                                      // 72
   0,                                      // 73
   0,                                      // 74
   0,                                      // 75
   0,                                      // 76
   0,                                      // 77
   0,                                      // 78
   0,                                      // 79
   0,                                      // 80
   0,                                      // 81
   0,                                      // 82
   0,                                      // 83
   0,                                      // 84
   0,                                      // 85
   0,                                      // 86
   0,                                      // 87
   0,                                      // 88
   0,                                      // 89
   0,                                      // 90
   0,                                      // 91
   0,                                      // 92
   0,                                      // 93
   0,                                      // 94
   0,                                      // 95
   0,                                      // 96
   0,                                      // 97
   0,                                      // 98
   0,                                      // 99
   0,                                      // 100
   0,                                      // 101
   0,                                      // 102
   0,                                      // 103
   0,                                      // 104
   0,                                      // 105
   0,                                      // 106
   0,                                      // 107
   0,                                      // 108
   0,                                      // 109
   0,                                      // 110
   0,                                      // 111
   0,                                      // 112
   0,                                      // 113
   0,                                      // 114
   0,                                      // 115
   0,                                      // 116
   0,                                      // 117
   0,                                      // 118
   0,                                      // 119
   0,                                      // 120
   0,                                      // 121
   0,                                      // 122
   0,                                      // 123
   0,                                      // 124
   0,                                      // 125
   0,                                      // 126
   0,                                      // 127
   0,                                      // 128
   0,                                      // 129
   0,                                      // 130
   0,                                      // 131
   0,                                      // 132
   0,                                      // 133
   0,                                      // 134
   0,                                      // 135
   0,                                      // 136
   0,                                      // 137
   0,                                      // 138
   0,                                      // 139
   0,                                      // 140
   0,                                      // 141
   0,                                      // 142
   0,                                      // 143
   0,                                      // 144
   0,                                      // 145
   0,                                      // 146
   0,                                      // 147
   0,                                      // 148
   0,                                      // 149
   0,                                      // 150
   0,                                      // 151
   0,                                      // 152
   0,                                      // 153
   0,                                      // 154
   0,                                      // 155
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 156 USB
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 157 RFCORE RX/TX
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 158 RFCORE Error
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 159 AES
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 160 PKA
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 161 SMTimer
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // 162 MACTimer
#endif
};

//*****************************************************************************
//
// The following are constructs created by the linker, indicating where the
// the "data" and "bss" segments reside in memory.  The initializers for the
// for the "data" segment resides immediately following the "text" segment.
//
//*****************************************************************************
extern uint32_t _etext;
extern uint32_t _data;
extern uint32_t _edata;
extern uint32_t _bss;
extern uint32_t _ebss;

//
// And here are the weak interrupt handlers.
//
void 
NmiSR (void) 
{ 
    ResetISR(); 
    while(1)
    {
    } 
}


void 
FaultISR (void) 
{ 
    while(1)
    {
    } 
}


void 
IntDefaultHandler (void) 
{ 
    while(1)
    {
    }
}

void 
ResetISR (void)
{
    uint32_t *pui32Src, *pui32Dest;

    //
    // Workaround for PM debug issue
    //
    HWREG(SYS_CTRL_EMUOVR) = 0xFF; 

    //
    // Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM.
    //
    pui32Src = &_etext;
    for(pui32Dest = &_data; pui32Dest < &_edata; )
    {
        *pui32Dest++ = *pui32Src++;
    }

    //
    // Zero fill the bss segment.
    //
    __asm("    ldr     r0, =_bss\n"
          "    ldr     r1, =_ebss\n"
          "    mov     r2, #0\n"
          "    .thumb_func\n"
          "zero_loop:\n"
          "        cmp     r0, r1\n"
          "        it      lt\n"
          "        strlt   r2, [r0], #4\n"
          "        blt     zero_loop");

#ifdef CC2538_USE_ALTERNATE_INTERRUPT_MAP
    //
    // Enable alternate interrupt mapping
    //
    HWREG(SYS_CTRL_I_MAP) |= 1;
#endif

   //
   // Call the application's entry point.
   //
   main();

   //
   // End here if return from main()
   //
   while(1)
   {
   }
}
```

---

**cc2538_512_gcc.cmd**

```
/******************************************************************************
 *
 *
 * cc2538_512_gcc.cmd - Example GCC linker configuration file for CC2538
 *
 *
 *****************************************************************************/

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x200000, LENGTH = 0x0007FFD4
    FLASH_CCA (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0027FFD4, LENGTH = 12
    SRAM_NON_RETENTION (RWX) : ORIGIN =  0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
    SRAM_RETENTION (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x20004000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH= 0
    .data : AT(ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM_NON_RETENTION
    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM_NON_RETENTION
    .flashcca :
    { 
    } > FLASH_CCA   
}
```

---

Here is a printscreen that shows the configurations and the related files on the left side menu
[image]

Comment: @Artless noise, thank you. I could not understand what is wrong but it solves the problem, it might be good to post it as an answer. So I removed "#include "setup.c" " on startup_gcc.c then add #include <stdint.h> and "#define SYS_CTRL_EMUOVR 0x400D20B4" now it compiles correctly and the binary works fine on the EVM. It was the default code, It is another question to TI if they compile the code before publishing a code :)

Comment: It still outputs two warning message saying Description Resource Path Location Type
../cc2538_512_gcc.cmd contains output sections; did you forget -T? cc2328em_test    C/C++ Problem
cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00200000 cc2328em_test    C/C++ Problem

Do you know what to do with them?

Comment: do not build setup.c ... as it is already included in stup_gcc.c ... this way it is getting compiled twice ... or you can remove the include "setup.c" from setup_gcc/c

Comment: place an answer to this post (the 1 by @artless).. so one can know :) i say that after my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of startup_gcc.c is `#include "setup.c"`; do you see a problem? Don't build *setup.c* separately if you do this.

Reading the error message *multiple definition of '__cca'* will help; computers rarely lie.  You can compile this twice. Also, your *.flashcca* output section in the linker script has no input files and this should be fixed.

For example,

```
.flashcca :{*(.flashcca);} > FLASH_CCA
```

Without `*(.flashcca);`, the `.flashcca :{} > FLASH_CCA` is useless. The first *.flashcca* is an output section (ie. some place in final binary). The stuff inside the brackets is an *input section* (ie, your source/object).  A major choir of the linker is to take multiple *input sections* and place them in an output section.  The other job is to revolve external symbols; it can not do this when it has two of the same name provided; there is no way to know which on to use.  This is why you have *multiple definition of '__cca'*.